# JUnit failing from HeadlessException in program using java.awt/javax.swing

Tags: java, junit, ant

I have a Java project that I need to create a JUnit ant task and some tests for.
The tests should not be dependent on the environment.
The program that is to be tested uses a lot of GUI-related things from `java.awt` and `javax.swing`.
I have tried various settings and modifications, but for some reason the test always dies from `java.awt.HeadlessException`.
I have searched for a solution for this problem without luck - any help would be appreciated.

(I am using `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)` on `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`)

I have added the code below to my build.xml:

```
  <target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit>
      <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true"/>
      <sysproperty key="java.awt.headless" value="true"/>
      <classpath>
        <path refid="junit.class.path"/>
        <path refid="libs.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.test.path}"/>
      </classpath>
      <batchtest>
        <fileset dir="${build.test.path}">
          <include name="**/*Test*"/>
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
      <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
    </junit>
  </target>
```

This is the output of the JUnit test:

```
[junit] Test org.sampleprogram.MyAppTest FAILED
[junit] Testsuite: org.sampleprogram.MySomethingTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.311 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: testSample(org.sampleprogram.MySomethingTest):    Caused an ERROR
[junit] null
[junit] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MySomething.initStaticProperties(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MySomething.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MySomethingTest.testSample(Unknown Source)
[junit] Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
[junit]     at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask(HeadlessToolkit.java:236)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTADefaultInputMap.getDefaultModifier(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTADefaultInputMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextAreaDefaultInputMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextAreaUI.getRTextAreaInputMap(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaUI.installKeyboardActions(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.installUI(BasicTextUI.java:805)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:666)
[junit]     at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setUI(JTextComponent.java:328)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.setRTextAreaUI(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.init(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea.init(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.init(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.gui.TextArea.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MyApp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Test org.sampleprogram.MySomethingTest FAILED
```

And if I change `headless` in `build.xml` to `false`, it still fails but the result changes to this:

```
[junit] Testsuite: org.sampleprogram.MyAppTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.471 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: testSample(org.sampleprogram.MyAppTest):    Caused an ERROR
[junit] Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
[junit] java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
[junit]     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
[junit]     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
[junit]     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
[junit]     at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
[junit]     at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
[junit]     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.<clinit>(RepaintManager.java:233)
[junit]     at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4792)
[junit]     at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3313)
[junit]     at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setEditable(JTextComponent.java:1758)
[junit]     at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:309)
[junit]     at javax.swing.JTextArea.<init>(JTextArea.java:204)
[junit]     at javax.swing.JTextArea.<init>(JTextArea.java:140)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.gui.SampleTextArea.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MyApp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MyApp.initStaticProperties(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MyApp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.sampleprogram.MyAppTest.testSample(Unknown Source)
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Test org.sampleprogram.MyAppTest FAILED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [getMenuShortcutKeyMask](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/HeadlessToolkit.java#HeadlessToolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask%28%29) from `sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit`, the `Toolkit` used when in [headless](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) mode (*), will **always** throw this Exception :

```
public int getMenuShortcutKeyMask()
        throws HeadlessException {
        throw new HeadlessException();
    }
```

This method is called by [org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTADefaultInputMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jtstand/jtstand-editor/1.4.5/org/fife/ui/rtextarea/RTADefaultInputMap.java#RTADefaultInputMap.getDefaultModifier%28%29), so you won't be able to perform the tests as is.

(*)

> Default Toolkit Creation
>
> If a system property named java.awt.headless is set to true, then the
> headless implementation of Toolkit is used. Use the
> getDefaultToolkit() method of the Toolkit class to create an instance
> of headless toolkit:
>
> Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

Comment: Thanks a lot! `org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTADefaultInputMap` calls, `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`, which in headless mode returns `sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit`, which always throws `HeadlessException`, which means I can't run it in headless mode, right? So I set headless mode to `false`, but another(display-related-ish) error appeared.. I hope there is a way to test this from a regular *nix environment..(I still don't understand enough about ant/headless/the libraries in question to even understand if what I'm attempting is even possible)

Comment: @StubbornShowaGuy : setting headless to false won't fix the problems, because graphical libraries and devices will be called, that don't exist, so it will also fail. Read the link about _headless_ at the top of my answer.